# How to create an EC2 instance with specified password using python boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

how to set a password when launching instances with boto3?

[boto3 run_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances)

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Windows, Amazon Linux, Ubuntu, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an account password for logging in? This is highly dependent on what AMI you're launching. Typically UNIX, Linux, and BSD-based AMIs don't use a password at all: you supply an SSH key that the `cloud-init` subsystem places into the default user's account. All these systems *usually* work pretty much the same.

It's different for Windows I suppose.

But you need to clarify what system you're launching; an AMI ID would be great.

Comment: thanks.  If instance (which AMI subject to Unix/Linux) is not associated with a key pair,
how to set a valid username and password combination for logging in by SSH or VNC

Comment: It really depends on how the AMI is built. There's no universal method for this. Most pre-made images use `cloud-init`. You can learn more about using it at https://cloud-init.io/.

If you're building your own AMI, I recommend using cloud-init as well.